# What should we do when we want to have a view bigger than Phone?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4

The way Yelp seems doing it is that it uses UITableView

Hence, a lot of content can be put and users just scroll up and down.

Can I do that without UITableView?

What about if I want to use UIView instead?

-

I sort of figure out that UIScrollView is the way to do it. However for that to work we need to set up contentSize.

Why SDK doesn't just use UIScrollView width and height in specifying that contentSize?

Also how to get UIScrollView width and height.

For example, I set the height of my UIScrollView to 1000

However doing
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.bounds.size.width, scrollView.bounds.size.height);
    NSLog(@"Content Size: %f" , scrollView.bounds.size.height);
    NSLog(@"Content Size: %f" , scrollView.frame.size.height);

All produce 416 even though I set the height of the UIScrollView to be 1000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what UIScrollView is designed for.  Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 4):

You can probably create a `UIView` with a big frame and gesture recognizers to make it work but there is no point redoing what's been done. `UITableView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`. Scroll views are meant to present a canvas that is bigger than the viewport i.e. the user's screen. There is a good bit of customizations that you can do with them. So use `UIScrollView` to present that view.